# Is creating multiple cursors for the same table but different validation is a good practice

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am working on PL/SQL project and I have to do certain actions based on 7 validations.

All are on the same table, so I was planning to create 7 cursors each to have one validation in its where clause.

These cursors are not dependent on each other but I found it is easer than looping in one general cursor and then perform 7 IF statements inside it.

It is a good practice?

Comment: It's better to use single cursor other wise it takes more time to parse your query. Share what exactly is your specification.

Answer (score 3):

Seven cursors means seven context switches between PL/SQL and SQL engines. It's a little hard to parse from your brief description above the precise flow you need (stop after a validation fails? return no rows if any validations fails?), but generally I would encourage you to do as much work as you can in a single cursor (SELECT) and then pass back the results to your PL/SQL block.